# MariaDB cluster fails to create root user on second node

Tags: docker, mariadb

When I try to create a two node MariaDB cluster in Docker on Windows, I get this error:

> ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 8: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'

For the first node I run this

> docker run --network maria_db --name maria-0 -e MYSQL_INITDB_SKIP_TZINFO=yes -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes mariadb --wsrep-new-cluster --wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://maria-0,maria-1 --binlog-format=ROW --wsrep-on=1 --wsrep-provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so

And wait until it is ready for connections, then I open up a new terminal and run this:

> docker run --network maria_db --name maria-1 -e MYSQL_INITDB_SKIP_TZINFO=yes -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes mariadb --wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://maria-0,maria-1 --binlog-format=ROW --wsrep-on=1 --wsrep-provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so

I have tried to set a root password, but I get the same output.

The log for node two is pretty big, so i have created a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/dp85mpPg. I have tried to embed this log in this question, but it seems to not be possible to do so without linebreaking.

I really dont know what is causing this, but it maybe looks like the image tries to recreate the database on node two after it has synced the database? I dont know. This is new to me,

Hope someone knows what to do.

Comment: Basically this cant get to work on Windows because of a bug in volume mounts. The work around on Linux and Mac is to create a volume with a already created mysql folder for the data on all nodes, so the init does not happen. This cant be done on windows. I am left wtih two options: 1) picking another database for my project, or 2) waiting :( both makes me sad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it myself as part of something I call stack, https://github.com/mslot/stack. Build the Maria database image. It uses a consul as discovery tool.